# Shiny leaflet easyButton only fires once

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

I want a Shiny + Leaflet app to flick between global and national scales.  Clicking on country symbols drills down to that scale as intended.  To return from country view to global view I've added an easyButton.  It works on first click, but when the user drills down again to any country and clicks to return again to global view nothing happens.  Reproducible script:

```
require(shiny)
require(dplyr)
require(leaflet)

d = tibble(country = c(rep('China', 3), rep('Brazil', 3), rep('Canada', 3)),
           name = paste(country, rep(1:3,3)), count = sample(30:100,9),
           lon = c(105, 112, 110, -52, -54, -51, -95, -100, -93),
           lat = c(35, 33, 25, -10, -11, -12, 60, 63, 61))

dSum = d %>% group_by(country) %>% summarise(lon = mean(lon), lat = mean(lat), count = sum(count)) %>% rename(name = country)

renderMap = function(x){
  renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(x) %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(layerId = ~name, lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat, label = ~ name, radius = ~ pmax(3, 100 * sqrt(count/max(count)))) %>% 
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE, minZoom=2, maxZoom=18)
      ) %>% 
      addEasyButton(easyButton(
        icon="fa-backward", title="Refresh map", id = "refresh-map", 
        onClick = JS(" function(btn, map) { Shiny.onInputChange('my_easy_button', 'refresh'); }")))
  })
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mymap <- renderMap(dSum)

  # click on country
  observeEvent(input$mymap_marker_click, {
    countryname = input$mymap_marker_click$id
    message(countryname)
    output$mymap = renderMap(filter(d, country == countryname))
  })

  # click on refresh button
  observeEvent(input$my_easy_button, { output$mymap = renderMap(dSum) })
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head( tags$style(HTML("#mymap { position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100vw; height: 100vh !important; }
                             .container-fluid { margin:0; padding:0; } ")) ),
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The effect is also seen when simulating click with jQuery - e.g. `$('.easy-button-button').click()`.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I have no idea why this happens, but I did see another [demo](https://community.rstudio.com/t/leaflet-easy-button-detect/20390) that included 2 `easyButtonState` methods and in that case it will repeatedly make the observer fire in response to `input` changes as the states toggle back and forth. I wish I could be of more help.

Comment: Ah excellent. It seems nesting inside `states - list(easyButtonState(...))` with addition of `Shiny.onInputChange('my_easy_button', 'free');` inside the onClick function makes it work. Thanks Ben.

Answer (score 1):

It is even easier than you suggest. Shiny only reacts to changes, so you need to include a change in your JS function call. Using `Math.random()` does the trick.

```r
onClick = JS("function(btn, map){Shiny.onInputChange('easyButtonIdentify', Math.random());}")
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Ben's comment:

```
<leaflet_obj>  %>% 
      addEasyButton(easyButton(states = list(
        easyButtonState(stateName = 'onestate', 
                        icon="fa-backward", title="Refresh map", #id = "refresh-map", 
                        onClick = JS(" function(btn, map) { Shiny.onInputChange('my_easy_button', 'refresh'); Shiny.onInputChange('my_easy_button', 'free'); }"))
        )
      ))
  })
}
```

No idea why this works.